# How to login through a keycloak service account?

Tags: node.js, keycloak, service-accounts

I can't figure out how to prepare the POST command to access keycloak with a service account.

I'm using nodejs to access a clean keycloak 4.8.1 server and tried a few configurations of POST but couldn't have success in log in through service account yet.

I'm having a hard time trying to simply login to a client through service account. I've tried some configurations but never got success in log in. The last code I've tried was like this:

```
function serviceAccountAuthenticate (client) {
  return function login (realmName, secret) {
    const clientSecret = `procempa-admin:${secret}`;
    const basicToken = `Basic: ${btoa(clientSecret)}`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const req = {
        form: {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'},
        authorization: basicToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      };
      const url = `${client.baseUrl}/realms/${realmName}/protocol/openid-connect/token`;
      request.post(url, req, (err, resp, body) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }

        // Check that the status cod
        if (resp.statusCode !== 200) {
          return reject(body);
        }

        return resolve(body);
      });
    });
  };
}
```

and the result was sad like this:

```
{ form: { grant_type: 'client_credentials' },
  authorization: 'Basic: cHJvY2VtcGEtYWRtaW46YzZmZmUxNzUtNDgyZS00NjMxLWE5YjEtMTBjNWIyNjZlYzZi',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
Error {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Invalid client credentials"}
```

Comment: Please have a look [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470477/how-to-get-keycloak-users-via-rest-without-admin-account) another helpful link is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238839/access-keycloak-rest-admin-api-using-a-service-account-client-credential-grant)